# Angular expression get property of object from equal property in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, expression

Sorry for the bad title, couldn't really think of an apropriate one.

Anyways, I have an array of objects, which are all listed in a ng-repeat. Then, I want to find the object in another array of objects, which has the same id as the one above and get another of its properties.

I hope this example code will simplify things:

```
$scope.discussions = [
    {
        recipient: {
            id: 'theid'
        },
        messages: []
    }
];

$scope.friends = [
    {
        id: 'theid',
        online: false
    }

];
```

And in my view I have:

```
<div ng-repeat="discussion in discussions">
    <div>Online = {{//code here}}</div>
</div>
```

Tried both

```
ng-class="{online: {{friends.some(fr => fr.id == discussion.recipient._id).online}}; }"
```

and

```
ng-class="{online: friends.some(fr => fr.id == discussion.recipient._id).online }"
```

Comment: Well you could use the Javascript [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to help you determine the first element of `friends` where the ids match.

Comment: I couldn't really get it to work, I am not quite sure what I can use withing an angular expression ;/

Comment: I suggest calling some function that you define in your angular controller that finds the matching element in your friends array.

Comment: Problem is this boolean I want to parse is going to be changing quite a lot, I would like to update all of the changes to the view instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to define a function within your angular controller that can match a single `discussion` to the matching element in your `$scope.friends`.  That function might look like this (this can be improved, but it gets the job done):

```
$scope.findMatchingId = function (discussion) {
    var matchingFriend;
    $scope.friends.some(function (friend) {
        if (friend.id === discussion.recipient.id) {
            matchingFriend = friend;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    return matchingFriend;
};
```

Then in your html, you can just call that function on the element within the ng-repeat like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="discussion in discussions">
     <div>Online = {{findMatchingId(discussion)}}</div>
</div>
```

See this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/y4yMU2ab5cTX4RBEX5t7?p=preview)

Comment: It works, but it is not getting updated dynamically, like angular should, so if the value changes, the view remains unupdated ;/

Comment: @user3127242 I updated the plnkr to allow you to change the id of the friends.  I'm not sure what kind of update problems you are having, but the plnkr seems to update the views fine.

Comment: I have the discussion.recipient._id and I want to find the according friend and get its online status. Then, after the status is updated, I want it to change instantly in the view, which is not hapening until a page refresh is done ;/

Comment: @user3127242 If you are trying to show/hide based on the `online` property, you should use an [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).  Like this `<div ng-show="findMatchingId(discussion).online">Online = {{findMatchingId(discussion)}}</div>`

Comment: I have no problems with that, but the property is online being updated on init, and then no changes appear in the view ;/

Comment: @user3127242 I don't know what else could cause that.  The only this I can think of, is that something is binding to the wrong property.  Best of luck.